# Java ProcessBuilder().start() vs. NodeJS require('child_process').spawn()

Tags: java, node.js, processbuilder, spawn

We have a legacy application written in NodeJS and that application is calling a C++ application with `require('child_process').spawn()` method. The working time of C++ application is around 5 seconds.

Then I convert the NodeJS application to Java, and I am using `ProcessBuilder().start()` to call the same C++ application. Now it takes around 30 seconds the application to finish.

Do you know what could be the reason or is this a normal behaviour? The C++ application creates some files (around 20). What could be the reason and how can I improve this? Thank you

Comment: It is impossible to answer without additional profiling.

Answer (score 1):

`require('child_process').spawn()` is not a sync call.That method spawns the child process asynchronously, without blocking the Node.js event loop.

If you try `require('child_process').spawnSync()` it will wait C++ process.

So i think in Java you need to run this process with a new thread. In documentation it says

> Note that this class is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a
>   ProcessBuilder instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies one of the attributes structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

[DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

If you want to run it async maybe you need to create new instance instead of using single instance.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```